# Approaches to running CLI applications in Kubernetes?

Tags: command-line-interface, kubernetes

I'm interested to know tried and tested techniques for running CLI applications against a Kubernetes cluster.

Our services take the form of docker images. It seems logical that our CLI applications should also be docker images. This gives us a bunch of options to run CLI applications against services inside our Kubernetes cluster.

Ultimately we can run the images locally (`docker run`) run them inside the cluster (`kubectl run`) or have a "noop" container we run commands in (`kubectl exec`). The main downside of running outside is we don't get context (like DNS). But running inside seems like it might be slow: slow start up as image is pulled on to a node and the latency involved in running an interactive terminal over HTTP. The "noop" container feels a bit hacky.

Does anyone have any other approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Jobs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/#running-an-example-job) for this:

> A job creates one or more pods and ensures that a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the job tracks the successful completions. When a specified number of successful completions is reached, the job itself is complete. Deleting a Job will cleanup the pods it created.

Comment: That sounds great for batch work or a cron job equiv - but doesn't feel like it's intended for an interactive CLI image

Comment: Sorry, what do mean under "Interactive CLI image"?

Comment: I'm talking about a docker image that will be used as a command line interface tool. One I may fire multiple commands at. Think the `mysql` command, a `python` interpreter, or even something like `vim`.

Comment: You can do this with `kubectl exec` command. Just create image that hangs forever after start and run you app as `kubectl exec POD <your_cli_app> <args>

Comment: I'm familiar with `kubectl exec` but am wondering if there's an approach that doesn't involve running "noop" containers on all a bunch of my nodes. I'll update the q.